# Using printf() in C to print out this character symbol ÿ (ASCII 152)

Tags: c, printf, ascii

I am unable to print out this special symbol ÿ (ASCII 152). Looking at the debugger I can see the variable is saving the special symbol. At the moment it just prints a space.

My simplified code looks something like this

Struct:

```
typedef struct BufferDescriptor {
    char* cb_head;
}* pBuffer;

//Current object
pBuffer ptr_Buffer;
```

Line that adds symbol to cb_head:

```
//Calling addsymbol, the symbol used is EOF
addsymbol(ptr_Buffer, EOF);

Buffer* addsymbol(Buffer p, char symbol){
    p->cb_head[add] = symbol;
}
```

My printf, I already checked the value of variable buffer and it contains the ÿ symbol.
But it just prints out a space... Is there something maybe machine dependent or something about ASCII that I am missing.

```
printf("%c",buffer);
```

Comment: Why would `EOF` convert to `152`? In the extended ASCII table I am looking at your symbol is shown for `0xFF` but it depends on the system. True ASCII only goes to `127` or  `0x7F`.

Comment: What's the type of `buffer` in your code? If it's `char*` or `struct BufferDescriptor` or `pBuffer` or anything besides `char`, you can't print it with `%c`.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, there's to many unknowns about your code. Also please refresh about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Maybe you use a wrong character encoding. What OS do you use? What is your character encoding? Please [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: My apologies I took out some of the code , I thought was irrelevant, But also, I am able to print out normal characters, that I have tested.

Comment: I am running this on Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise on Windows 10

Comment: ÿ is character code 255 on a code page like 1252.  In other words `(char)EOF`.  That's what the debugger will show you.  Whether you can see it when the program runs depends on the active code page of the console.  Default is an OEM code page like 437 or 850, which maps character code 255 to a non-breaking space.  Lots of existing posts talk about switching the console to utf8.

Comment: In `addsymbol(ptr_Buffer, EOF);` you pass `ptr_Buffer` which is a pointer to a struct that contains a `char *`. The code `p->cb_head[add] = symbol;` in of `addsymbol`'s implementation is incomplete. It looks like you want to append or overwrite a character of a string pointed to by `cb_head`. It is unclear what `buffer` is in `printf("%c",buffer);`. A valid argument for `%c` would be an `int` (or a `char` or other type that can be converted to `int`). If it is a pointer you would take parts of the pointer address as a character value to be printed, not a character of a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the same number is showing up differently in different programs it's probably a [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) problem. There are many, many, many different ways to interpret the number 152 into a character. Each application can use a different encoding. It sounds like your editor and wherever you're printing to are using different encodings.

There is no ASCII 152. ASCII is 7-bits, only to 127.

There are many, many, many [extended encodings of ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) that add an 8th bit to cover 128-255. They share the same encodings for the first 127 characters, [after that they diverge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Latin_character_sets_(computing)#Comparison_table). CP 437 and [CP 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) have `ÿ` as 152. [Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) and [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) `ÿ` is 255. Most modern stuff uses [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8) which represents `ÿ` as two bytes, `c3 bf`.

152 is nothing in Latin-1 and nothing in UTF-8.

What's probably happening is some things are using UTF-8 (152 is invalid) and some are using CP 850 (152 is `ÿ`). Check the character encodings of your IDE and whatever you're using to display.

Comment: Thank you it was indeed an issue with encoding